# Why the top few rows disappear after using query in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

[image]

Hi everyone,

I have 2 tabs in the google sheet:

1. Form Responses (collecting the data from google form) [First screenshot]
2. Query [2nd screenshot]

Based on the 2 screenshot above, may I know why I'm only able to get the data started from row 8 in Form Responses after using the `QUERY` function in google sheet?

As you can see from the 2nd screenshot, there is no `Teacher 1, Teacher 2,Teacher 3, Teacher 4` although the Action are also `Initial Entry`.

I couldn't figure out the reason, hope to get some advise. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the optional headers argument and see if that helps?

```
=query('Form Responses'!A:AD, "Select A, B, C where C = 'Initial Entry' label A 'Timestamp', B 'Name', C 'Action'", 0)
```

Comment: Yes, it works now, I never pay attention to optional parameter as I thought it is not important, thanks!